# How to import TensorMetric in pytorch lighting？

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I want to import `TensorMetric` :

```
from pytorch_lightning.metrics.metric import TensorMetric
```

The program throws an exception:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_lightning.metrics'

My environment is:

- Python 3.8.13
- tokenizers==0.9.2
- torch==1.5.1
- transformers==3.4.0
- pytorch-lightning==0.9.0
- tensorboard==2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.9` is a very old version of Lightning and a lot has changed/improved since then. I would recommend you to use the latest version of PyTorch Lightning (1.6).

Also, we have metrics as a separate library now [TorchMetrics](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).